# 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect

Tags: twitter, web-crawler, twitter4j

It's the first time for me using twitter4j i got project from github trying to run it to see the result of how using twitter4j and when i run the Crawler class i got this

```
0 [Twitter Stream consumer-1[initializing]] INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl - Establishing 
  connection. 5617 [Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]] INFO 
  twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl - 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages
  /auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access 
  token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
```

i guess from `Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret` that i should change the proprieties of twitter4j.proprieties !!? am i right or false ? and how can i change the proprieties of it ? 
Can someone help ?

Comment: After creation of app you will get consumer key/secret which you can configure in your program using configurationbuilder.

Comment: Thanks for replying and help . i didn't see consumer key/secret but i have APP key/secret what's the difference between APP and consumer ? and what is configuration builder ?

Answer (score -1):

I got the similar error with using `twitter4j 3.0.x` version. I solved it by updating `twitter4j` to the `4.0.0` version

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It may be beneficial to include **why** updating from `3.X` to `4.X` resolved the issue, as blindly updating is not always an option for every implementation.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following options given in [this](http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html) link to set the Keys:

1. **via twitter4j.properties**: Save a standard properties file named "twitter4j.properties". Place it to either the current directory, root of the classpath directory.

> debug=true
>       oauth.consumerKey=*********************
>       oauth.consumerSecret=******************************************
>       oauth.accessToken=**************************************************
>       oauth.accessTokenSecret=******************************************

2. **via ConfigurationBuilder**: You can use [ConfigurationBuilder](http://twitter4j.org/ja/javadoc/twitter4j/conf/ConfigurationBuilder.html) class to configure Twitter4J programatically as follows:

> ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
>   cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
>   .setOAuthConsumerKey("*********************")
>   .setOAuthConsumerSecret("******************************************") 
>   .setOAuthAccessToken("**************************************************")
>   .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("******************************************");
>   TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()); Twitter twitter =
>   tf.getInstance();

3. **via System Properties**: You can configure Twitter4J via System properties. Note that you need "twitter4j." prefix.

> $ java -Dtwitter4j.debug=true
>       -Dtwitter4j.oauth.consumerKey=*********************
>       -Dtwitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret=******************************************
>       -Dtwitter4j.oauth.accessToken=**************************************************
>       -Dtwitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret=******************************************
>       -cp twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar:yourApp.jar yourpackage.Main

4. **via environment variables**: Note that you need "twitter4j." prefix.

> $ export twitter4j.debug=true $ export
>   twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey=********************* $ export
>   twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret=******************************************
>   $ export
>   twitter4j.oauth.accessToken=**************************************************
>   $ export
>   twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret=******************************************
>   $ java -cp twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar:yourApp.jar yourpackage.Main